# Warehouse Inventory Database Modal

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, web

I got my first professional project where I have to create a warehouse inventory web application. I have completed the front-end however I am stuck on the database modal - I'm not entirely sure if I got it right.

(ignore the scribble)
[image]

Basically, the company only needs to keep track of their stock level in each of their warehouse and do not need to add supplier details or any cost/sale prices.

These are all the tables and links I could think of however, even though this might work (or not), is this the correct design modal? (specifially the central table)
.
.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right and Wrong are not absolute. That being said, here is my opinion on your model:

1) Are you sure purchases and sales should be two different tables? They have the same fields. Make them one and add a field that determines whether it's a purchase or sale.

2) The fact that the stock table has the same keys (warehouse,item) that the sales/purchases,inventory, and transfers table does not make it a logical centre table. My design would be:

- Tables barcodes,items,warehouses as you already have them.
- The remaining tables should have foreign keys on items,or warehouses, or both, whatever exists. There is no reason to make a 2-field FK towards the stock-locations table
- The transfers item should have both warehouse_from and warehouse_to FK referenceing warehouses. And item, of course.